# Defining tags help

Tags: support, tags

I have ~900 reputation and I am trying to define the tag "niv" by going to [this page](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tags/niv/info)

but all I see under the big paragraph are the options "edit pending", "history", and "excerpt history"

Do I have enough rep to flesh out what the tag "niv" is, and if so, where and how?

Comment: ok, I just copied and pasted the link myself, and this time I see a bright blue "edit tag info" button --- that's weird, no way I could have missed that.

Comment: But now I also see a definition. Perhaps I don't have enough rep to make a new one, only to edit an existing one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You caught the system at a bad time. Tag edits have to be approved by a couple users. You have the rep to suggest edits but not to approve them. In between the time an edit is suggested by anybody and such a time as it is either approved or rejected by a mod or a couple higher rep users, editing is locked for that tag.

The "edit pending" message was for real. Somebody had, minutes before, proposed an edit to that tag and it was pending approval. I approved it a few minutes back, so now anyone is free to edit again—hence you see something different now.